# Why is UserAgent affecting my NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection

I have this code in my AppDelegate:

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

and I am running a NSURLSessionDownloadTask in webViewDidFinishLoad like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gps.com/Intel.js"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        // Save this following url to load the file
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)");
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
    NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];

    [_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];

    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PrivacyView" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    NSLog(@"PRIVACY VIEW!: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAUNCH_KEY]);
}
```

What happens when I run my app is that the download task is running non-stop but as soon as I remove the UserAgent script from my AppDelegate, the downloadtask works as it's suppose to and downloads the javascript file ONCE. Any help to get the downloadtask to run ONCE or to enlighten me why the UserAgent script would cause such an error would be greatly appreciated!

ADDITIONAL INFO:

My console log looks like this because the downloadtask is running so many times:

```
2017-06-01 14:48:50.009898-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:48:51.019193-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:48:51.250776-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:48:52.767284-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:48:52.968515-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:48:55.018189-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:48:55.124841-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:48:57.265404-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:48:57.265980-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:48:59.033294-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:48:59.151356-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:49:02.547727-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:49:02.549679-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
2017-06-01 14:49:04.801953-0700 GPS[1664:311236] PRIVACY VIEW!: Yes
2017-06-01 14:49:04.939535-0700 GPS[1664:311236] BLAST OFF! CODE HAS LANDED :)
```